# golang testscript .txtar syntax for text CONTAINED in stderr or stdout

Tags: go

I am learning how to test a cli program using https://github.com/rogpeppe/go-internal **testscript** module.

When I use this line in my `.txtar` file:

```
stderr /No help topic/gm
```

...and the actual error output is:

```
No help topic for 'totalfoobar'
```

I get the error `usage: stderr [-count=N] 'pattern'`.

I've looked at the docs [here](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/rogpeppe/go-internal@v1.11.0/testscript) and to be honest it's hard to follow. I don't see any explanations of what `-count=N` means.

I tried all of the following variants:

```
stderr -count=1 No help topic for 'totalfoobar'
stderr No help topic for 'totalfoobar'
stderr *No help topic*
```

and no matter the string, the assertion still fails with the same error.

Q: How do I much a **substring** of the total stderr / stdout outputs, for more flexible tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote the pattern with single quotes:

```
stderr 'No help topic'
```

The lines are parsed by [(*TestScript).parse](https://github.com/rogpeppe/go-internal/blob/3fbe0b6b66f19f66f2092de2551fd00ada865690/testscript/testscript.go#L1194-L1198):

```golang
// parse parses a single line as a list of space-separated arguments
// subject to environment variable expansion (but not resplitting).
// Single quotes around text disable splitting and expansion.
// To embed a single quote, double it: 'Don”t communicate by sharing memory.'
func (ts *TestScript) parse(line string) []string
```

And the result is passed as the `args` parameter to [scriptMatch](https://github.com/rogpeppe/go-internal/blob/3fbe0b6b66f19f66f2092de2551fd00ada865690/testscript/cmd.go#L600-L664) finally. The implementation of scriptMatch shows that besides the optional `-count` flag, it expects only **1** argument. If `No help topic` is not quoted, it will be parsed as **3** arguments, which does not meet the expectation:

```golang
extraUsage := ""
want := 1
// [code truncated]
if len(args) != want {
    ts.Fatalf("usage: %s [-count=N] 'pattern'%s", name, extraUsage)
}
```

BTW, it compiles the pattern like this:

```golang
re, err := regexp.Compile(`(?m)` + pattern)
```

Bear in mind that you should write the regular expression in the Go flavor syntax.

Comment: OMG!!! that works! I can't believe I didn't think of that. Thx for the proper explanation too - I just get lost when I try to follow what the actual golang code is doing - bit too advanced for me.